# How to increment minor using pbr python

Tags: python, release-management

I am using pbr to auto increment the version number. But every time after tagging, only last digit of version is getting incremented. How to increment middle number of version?

Comment: Are you using Git tags?

Comment: @MetallimaX yes, I am using git tags

Comment: Have you tried changing the tag to a major version?

Comment: @MetallimaX no. I also don&amp;#39;t know when pbr will increment major version. I added tag "v0.0.2";. Now, packages have 0.0.3.devN version

Comment: If I'm not wrong, pbr is refering to the git tag. So changing the git tag will change pbr version.

Comment: @MetallimaX yes, you are right. But suppose I have tagged 0.0.2 and now 0.0.3.devN is in use. But I don't want 0.0.3 version. I want directly 1.0.0 and tagging 1.0.0 will generate release artifact. I will not have any Pre-relase artifact for 1.0.0 version